# How do you get the name of an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

If you have an object `myObject`, what function can you use to get its name? I've tried stuff like `myObject.name`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get the name of the variable that an object was stored in. In fact, multiple variables can refer to a single object (which one would be the "name"?), probably the very reason you asked.

If it is important, I would suggest setting `myObject.name` when you create the object and then access it later, or perhaps add an additional parameter to your function that accepts the necessary information.

Comment: +1 setting the name to use it later, this is arguably the best way to do what you want cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Even if you could, which of the multiple variables that could be pointing at the object would you want?

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question about this in PHP.
The short answer is "you can't", but the longer one is "you can to a certain extent".

Here's an example:

```
test1={};
test2={};
test1b=test1;

function findName(ref){
   for(var i in window)
      if(window[i]===ref)
         alert('Found: '+i);
}

findName(test1);
```

The result of the example would be two different popups one with 'test1' and another one with 'test1b'.

Again, this is an **example**, no need for bashing about using global variables, etc...

**Edit:** Come to think of it, I'm pretty sure I needed something like this for debugging, and it seemed to work out nicely. But bear in mind it isn't something you should rely on.